# vim encodings: latin1 and utf-8

Tags: vim, character-encoding

Here's my problem:

- when I open the file, I get this message from vim:

  ```
  "myfilename.sql" [converted] 78565L, 10487381C
  ```
- if I do `:set` i get:

  ```
  Options
    backspace=2         colorcolumn=+1      formatoptions=qc    scrolloff=15        smartindent         textwidth=80        visualbell
    backup              expandtab           ignorecase          shiftwidth=4        syntax=sql          ttyfast             t_vb=
    bomb                filetype=sql        number              showcmd             tabstop=4           ttymouse=sgr
    backupdir=~/.vim/backup
    comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,:--,://
    define=\c\<\(VARIABLE\|DECLARE\|IN\|OUT\|INOUT\)\>
    directory=~/.vim/tmp
    fileencoding=utf-8
    fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,default,latin1
    matchpairs=(:),{:},[:],<:>
    omnifunc=sqlcomplete#Complete
    viminfo='10,"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
  ```
- I have the characters visible like this:

  [image: vim bad encoding]
- I found that if I reload & force encoding latin1 with `:e ++enc=latin1` I get right accents, but *not all*:

  [image: vim almost good encoding]
- So I found out (the only solution) to get all the right visible encoding is to manually force back to utf8: `:set encoding=utf8` then I get:

  [image: vim good encoding]
- if I do `:set` i get:

  ```
  --- Options ---
    backspace=2         encoding=utf-8      formatoptions=qc    scrolloff=15        smartindent         textwidth=80        visualbell
    backup              expandtab           ignorecase          shiftwidth=4        syntax=sql          ttyfast             t_vb=
    colorcolumn=+1      filetype=sql        number              showcmd             tabstop=4           ttymouse=sgr
    backupdir=~/.vim/backup
    comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,:--,://
    define=\c\<\(VARIABLE\|DECLARE\|IN\|OUT\|INOUT\)\>
    directory=~/.vim/tmp
    fileencoding=latin1
    fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,default,latin1
    matchpairs=(:),{:},[:],<:>
    omnifunc=sqlcomplete#Complete
    viminfo='10,"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
  ```
- As you can see, I see `fileencoding=latin1` so I try to force it to utf8: `:set fileencoding=utf-8`. I save it `:wq` and whenever I want to re-open it nothing has changed, *I still have to do all of this to get a proprer display* with good accents!
- The only thing I want from now is to save it so that I can re-open it without having all of this to do to get it right. What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you first `:set encoding=utf8` and then `:e ++enc=latin1 filename`?

Comment: *this is not about question*, please tell me what font you use?

Comment: @Зелёный Source Code Pro ExtraLight 12-point Why?

Comment: @IngoKarkat It doesn't work: i get text like `place situÃ©e avant ou aprÃ¨s`

Comment: Ah, so your file is not in latin1, but indeed utf-8. So let's try  `:set encoding=utf8` and then `:e ++enc=utf-8 filename`

Comment: @IngoKarkat When I do `:set encoding=utf8` it changes the display but not the good one (like it does with `:set encoding=latin1`) if I try then `:e ++enc=utf-8 otherfile.sql` it creates a new empty file...

Comment: @OlivierPons I suspect that you have messed up the file encoding by `:w`. can you show the output of `file yourFile` or `file -i yourFile` in terminal?

Comment: @Kent `file -i file.sql
file.sql: text/plain; charset=utf-8` then `file file.sql file.sql: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines`

Comment: @OlivierPons open vim, what's `set encoding?` output?

Comment: Do you have any encoding settings in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @Kent When I open vim if i try `:set encoding` i get `encoding=latin1`

Comment: @OlivierPons add `set encoding=utf-8` into your vimrc, and open that file with vim again.

Comment: @Kent If I try this, it almost works except 2-3 strange characters. It seems it was the right way to go, may I ask you to answer here so I can check it as the good answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

encoding, and fileencoding are two options in vim. please read the help doc for details.

If your file was encoded as UTF-8, the easiest way to read it is, set `encoding=utf-8` and `fileencoding=utf-8` too.

You can add those lines in your vimrc, to make it as default encoding option.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: I had a similar problem with international characters displaying as ▒, and it was fixed by

```
:set termencoding=utf-8
```

Longer answer: Here are the three related settings.  Usually they automatically do the right thing, but if they don't, you can set them.

> - **:set encoding** - set the encoding used to read the file
> - **:set fileencoding** - set the encoding to use when saving the file
> - **:set termencoding** - set the encoding to use to display characters to your terminal

The odd results you described might happen if, for example, the file is UTF-8 but Vim is reading it as Latin1, and at the same time your terminal is UTF-8 but Vim is writing to the terminal as Latin1.  In this case, the characters could look correct even though everything is wrong under the hood.  You can check this hypothesis by putting your cursor on the character in question and pressing `ga` to find its encoded value.